# 2013 farm installation - Workflow Installation

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, installation, workflow-manager

As far as I remember I need to install Workflow Manager on a non-SharePoint server as it's not installed part of SP install like Office web app. Is this a true statement.

Do I need to install Workflow Manager If I use Nintex workflow?

Should it' be part of my farm topology drawing?

Answer (score 2):

WFM can be installed on 1 or 3 SharePoint servers in the farm, if you go that route. You do not have to install it on a dedicated machine. It will all depend on your usage scenario/load, of course. You can always move it later to a dedicated machine if needed.

You do not need WFM for Nintex Workflows.

Answer (score 1):

**As far as I remember I need to install Workflow Manager on a non-SharePoint server as it's not installed part of SP install like Office web app. Is this a true statement.**

No, it's not a true statement, where you have 4 scenarios to install Workflow Manager.

- Workflow Manager is installed on a server that is part of the SharePoint 2013 farm. Communication takes place by using HTTP.
- Workflow Manager is installed on a server that is part of the SharePoint 2013 farm. Communication takes place by using HTTPS.
- Workflow Manager is installed on a server that is NOT part of the SharePoint 2013 farm. Communication takes place by using HTTP.
- Workflow Manager is installed on a server that is NOT part of the SharePoint 2013 farm. Communication takes place by using HTTPS.

for more details check [INSTALL AND CONFIGURE WORKFLOW MANAGER FOR SHAREPOINT 2013](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/05/06/install-and-configure-workflow-manager-for-sharepoint-2013/)

**Do I need to install Workflow Manager If I use Nintex workflow?**

Nintex Workflow or K2 didn't need to install Workflow Manager.